# C program that sorts in ascending order difference of two consecutive array elements

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I need to make a program that will sort the difference of consecutive array elements in ascending order. For exemple: the difference between first and second element is the smallest, the difference between second and 3rd is bigger and so on. I can't come up with a good algorithm to sort the array in desired way. The only thing I've come up with is switching places of 2 elements, then if order isn't right switch again and keep that until its sorted. I'm pretty sure its not well executed either.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void InputArray(int a[], int size);
void PrintArray(int a[], int size);
void sort(int a[], int size);

void main(){
    int a[100], i, n;
do{
    printf("Number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
} while (n < 1 || n > 100);

InputArray(a, n);
sort(a, n);
PrintArray(a, n);
printf("\n");
}

void InputArray(int a[], int size){
    printf("Enter array elements:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}
void sort(int a[], int size){
    int i, temp;
for (i = 0; ;i++){
    if ((a[i] - a[i + 1]) < (a[i + 1] - a[i + 2]))
        break;
    temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[i + 1];
    a[i + 1] = temp;

    if (i == size - 1){
        temp = a[size - 1];
        a[size - 1] = a[0];
        a[0] = temp;
        i = -1;
    }
 }
 }
  void PrintArray(int a[], int size){
    printf("Sorted array:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
```

Example output:

```
 Number of elements: 4
 Enter array elements:
 1 3 7 12
 Sorted array:
 1 7 12 3
```

But I'm getting 3 1 7 12 during testing.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand this at all.

Comment: why isn't `1 3 7 12 = 2 4 5` the solution of your example?

Comment: Its actually 
      `1 - 3 = -2
      3 - 7 = -4
      7 - 12 = -5`
That's not ascending order because there are negative

Answer (score 1):

A starting point could be to create a N^2 2D matrix with all the differences between all elements and then use a backtracking solution.

You have a set of taken and candidate elements.
Initially
taken = []
candidate =[1,3,7,12]

You select two elements to create the first difference.
Then you select a third element that satisfies the requirement for ascending order.

If you find one you proceed, if you don't you stop and go back to a point where you can change the elements taken.

If you reach a point where you will have found a solution that satisfies the requirements you return it, otherwise you keep looking into your search space.